# Using JQTouch inside Split View Controller

Tags: jqtouch, ipad

I have a split view controller-based iPad app that uses a Web View to load a jqTouch web app.

In portrait mode it looks fine, but in landscape mode (regardless of which orientation the app was launched in), the jqTouch page is wider than the viewport.

Is there a setting I can tweak (preferably via a call to `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:`) in the jqTouch view to get it to resize properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem boils down the fact that a `UIWebView` is not enough of a web browser for all of JQTouch's features to work as intended.

I ended up setting the height and width of the body to the height and width of the `UIWebView` thusly:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$('body').width(%f);$('body').children('div').not('.floaty').height(%f)", self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height]];
```

This is basically due to the fact that `onresize` doesn't get triggered, nor does `onorientationchange`. There may be cleaner ways of handling this by directly triggering those events.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider BeeDesk's fork:

```
http://labnote.beedesk.com/ipad-split-view-supports-on-an-jqtouchs-fork
```